# Why is the function prototype not working in this fiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, prototype-programming, function-prototypes

I was trying to print values of `vehicle` object [in my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/jrnug8dw/) using javascript function prototypes.

```js
function carDetails() {
  var car = new vehicle("Red", "Car");
  car.getPrice(100);

  // Define a function which will work as a method
  vehicle.prototype.price = function getPrice(amount) {
    car.price = amount;
  };

  document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = car.color;
  document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = car.type;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = car.price;

}

function vehicle(color, type) {
  this.color = color;
  this.type = type;
  //this.prototype.price = getPrice;
}

vehicle.prototype.getPrice = getPrice;

carDetails();
```

```html
<h1>
Javascript function prototypes
</h1>
<p id='color'></p>

<p id='type'></p>

<p id='price'></p>
```

Why is the `vehicle` object not getting printed?

Comment: Did you look the console? You can see "Uncaught TypeError: car.getPrice is not a function".

Comment: And why is your setter named as a getter?

Comment: @Ramsharan yes, but the function is there. Right?

Comment: You're not making use of the prototype facility at all in your code.

Comment: you can't do in this way.

Comment: @takendarkk Isn't that a prototype? I'm following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/object_prototype.htm) example. Where is the setter in my code?

Comment: There is no prototype anywhere in your code and your setter is where you SET THE PRICE. `this.price = amount` You say you are following that tutorial yet you never once use `prototype` which is in step 1.

Comment: @takendarkk Oops, now I have added the prototype property and getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined`. `getPrice` is there as a prototype method, right?

Comment: How can I know? You didn't post your new code.

Answer (score 2):

```
function vehicle(color, type) {
  this.color = color;
  this.type = type;
  this.price = getPrice;
}

 car.getPrice(100);
```

the property is `price` in and your using `getPrice()`.

Also , set set functions on prototype to avoid functions objects from being created with each constructor call.

Comment: I have updated [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/jrnug8dw/) but no change in the output.

Comment: @student there were many issues with the code in the fiddle . i urge you to read more on function scope and prototype chains on MDN, mean while here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aht2fpts/1/, i've made some changes.

Comment: +3 for the fiddle. I would try to use `prototype`s in the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
function carDetails() {
  var car = new vehicle("Red", "Car");
  car.getPrice(100);

  document.getElementById("color").value = car.color;
  document.getElementById("type").value = car.type;
  document.getElementById("price").value = car.price;

}

// Define a function which will work as a method
function getPrice(amount) {
  this.price = amount;
}


function vehicle(color, type) {
  this.color = color;
  this.type = type;
  this.getPrice = getPrice;
}

carDetails();

It will work
```

Comment: and also u didnt implement any prototype in this code